# IOS objective C selector using the wrong scope

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scope, selector

I'm using a custom class to hold the initiation code for a particular set of UITextField settings and inputAccessoryView

```
@interface CustomCountKeyboard : NSObject
```

It has the below method for initialisation with a UITextField only

```
-(id) initWithField:(UITextField *)field {
    self = [super init];
    self.titleField = field;
    self.titleLabel = nil;

    self.titleField.inputAccessoryView = [self makeToolBarWithWidth:self.titleField.superview.frame.size.width];


    return self;
}
```

And the below method, used by the init method above, to add the accessory views. The doneBtn in the below code specifies a selector of DoneSelectingValue, which is defined elsewhere on the class.

```
-(UIToolbar *) makeToolBarWithWidth:(CGFloat) width {


    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44)];
    [toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];



    NSArray *segItemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"", @"c", @"+", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segItemsArray];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    UIBarButtonItem *segmentedControlButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:(UIView *)segmentedControl];

    self.segmentedControl = segmentedControl;

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(DoneSelectingValue)];

    UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:segmentedControlButtonItem,space,doneBtn, nil]];


    return toolBar;
}
```

XCode correctly warns me when this DoneSelectingValue method isn't defined on this class. This class has been used elsewhere and it correctly calls the DoneSelectingValue callback in this class.

However, in this instance, it was failing to call this method in the class. Confused, I added the same method definition in the surrounding ViewController, and it called that successfully. This suggests the scope of the selector is wrong.

The only difference between the usage of this code when it works, and this instance when it doesn't, is that the UITextField this time is in a UITableViewCell and the instantiation of the CustomCountKeyboard happens in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. If this code is needed, I can edit to provide.

If I put in breakpoints, XCode inspector shows the correct value (The CustomCountKeyboard instance) for 'self' at instantiation time, so the target should be being set correctly.

Any ideas?

Edit: On request, below is the initialisation code for the CustomCountKeyboard

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if( self.textField.text.length > 0 )  {

        NSDictionary *species =[self.filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.obs addObject:species];
        [self.textField setText:@""];
        [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
        self.filteredTableData = [self calculateFilteredResults:self.textField.text];
        [self.speciesTable reloadData];

    }
    else {
        TestSpeciesCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        CustomCountKeyboard *ff = [[CustomCountKeyboard alloc] initWithField:cell.countField];
        [ff StartSelecting];

    }

}
```

StartSelecting content added

```
- (void)StartSelecting {

    if( self.titleLabel != nil ) {
        self.titleLabel.hidden = true;
    }


    if( self.titleField != nil ) {
        self.titleField.hidden = false;
        [self.titleField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        [self.titleView becomeFirstResponder];
    }

}
```

Comment: where you create the instance for CustomCountKeyboard class?

Comment: Make sure, 1. Self is not nil at this point UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(DoneSelectingValue)];   2. Instance of CustomCountKeyboard class is not deallocated

Comment: @jailani Thanks for the help. I'll add the initialisation code. For the second comment: 1. According to XCode in the breakpoint, it's not null. 2. How do I tell if it's deallocated?

Comment: Please share complete code, you haven't shared code for methods `DoneSelectingValue` and `StartSelecting`. Have you added the method signature in the `.h` file of the `CustomCountKeyboard ` class?

Comment: @Kampai Okay, i've added the `StartSelecting` code. Both `DoneSelectingValue` method just have one `NSLog` in, to tell them apart. I haven't put any content in yet. The `DoneSelectingValue` method signature is in the `.h` file for `CustomCountKeyboard`.

Comment: Can you show the declaration/definition of the `DoneSelectingValue` method?  I will say it's unusual for a delegate method to not receive parameters; for example the *what* that is done selecting values would be useful to the delegate.

Comment: I think the issue is, you are not calling the selector using the instance of that class. Call selector from the class where you created CustomCountKeyboard. Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758245/how-to-call-selector-method-from-another-class

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks. Both `DoneSelectingValue` methods are as follows `-(void)DoneSelectingValue`. On your suggestion, I added a param to it `:(id)sender` and the `:` to the selector, but it made no difference.

Comment: @Kampai Thanks. I changed the `makeToolBarWithWidth` to be passed the target instead `-(void) makeToolBarWithWidth:(CGFloat)width withTarget:(id)target ` and called that after instantiation, so I'm definitely passing the correct class `CustomCountKeyboard *ff = [[CustomCountKeyboard alloc] initWithField:cell.countField];
        [ff makeToolBarWithWidth:self.view.frame.size.width  withTarget:ff];` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `If nil, the action message is passed up the responder chain where it may be handled by any object implementing a method corresponding to the selector held by the action property. The default value is nil.` That's from the documentation for the target property. I'm assuming it's as you said, and somehow the reference is being deallocated somehow, I just can't work out how.

Comment: Solved it, by keeping a reference to the CustomCountKeyboard. It was clearly being deallocated, still don't know how though, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out to be quite simple actually. On selecting of a table row I am instantiating a custom class of CustomCountKeyboard and using it to attach an inputAccessoryView to the field I pass to it. Unfortunately the target property on the UIBarButtonItem is weak, so doesn't stop the class being deallocated.

So by the time the `Done` button is clicked, the method has completed and the instance has been garbage collected, and consequently is actually not there. The system then instead bubbles the action selector up and does it on the view controller instead.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        TestSpeciesCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        CustomCountKeyboard *ff = [[CustomCountKeyboard alloc] initWithField:cell.countField];
        [ff makeToolBarWithWidth:self.view.frame.size.width  withTarget:ff];

        [ff StartSelecting];


}
```

Changed to:

`@property CustomCountKeyboard *countPicker;`

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        TestSpeciesCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        self.countPicker = [[CustomCountKeyboard alloc] initWithField:cell.countField];

        [self.countPicker StartSelecting];

}
```

Thanks to Kampai and trojanfoe for helping me to get there. I'd give you rep if I could.